# Possibility to get a US tourist visa quickly?

Tags: visas, usa, tourist-visas

I can see today that there are appointment slots available after 15th June for US visas in Mumbai. Is there any option to get an earlier appointment?

If someone cancels their appointment, can I apply? I didn't any way to know that.

Comment: Comment only based on my personal experience. There is a special fast track but you will need to have a really good reason for it ( mostly health related ). Also,it appears that even if not officially declared -  some visa Agents in some countries seem to be able to book earlier appointments and also "switch" appointees. Also I heard from a colleague that apparently when someone has cancelled their appointment, it is becoming automatically available in the system if not reserved for some reason - so checking for a few times or a few days might yield surprising results...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guidance is found on the [US State Department site](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html), beginning with the notation that:

> Nonimmigrant visa applicants are encouraged to apply at least three months in advance of the intended date of travel.

In Mumbai, the average interview wait time for nonimmigrant visas is 49 days (28 for Student/Exchange Visitor Visas).

> **Wait Time for Interview**
>   The estimated wait time to receive an interview appointment to apply at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate. (For emergency appointment requests: After checking the wait time where you will apply, if an expedited interview appointment is needed earlier due to an emergent situation, visit the [Embassy or Consulate Visa Section website](http://www.usembassy.gov/) where you will find specific instructions about making the request.)

The visa section of the US Consulate in Mumbai directs you to use www.ustraveldocs.com/in to make, change, or request an expedited appointment.